# SSRS IE 9 double scroll bars (2 vertical and 2 horizontal scroll bars) BUG?

Tags: internet-explorer, ssrs-2008-r2

I have been working on an SSRS report and it's been working fine the past few days. Today I made some small format changes (font color,size,weight etc.) and now when I see my report in IE9 it shows double scroll bars. When I open the report in Firefox, the report is just fine and only has 1 set of scroll bars as it should.

I don't mind the fact that it doesn't look very nice but what I don't like and I am sure some users will complain about is the fact that they will have to scroll down using the outside scroll bars to then be able to scroll to the right using the inside scroll bar because the outside scroll bar will not scroll far enough to the right.

Has anyone else experienced this and have a solution for it?

[image]

EDIT: I had a prior copy of the report that did not have the double scroll bars. I was able to recreate the double scroll bar issue in IE9 by simply increasing the width of the one of the columns in my report.

The bad thing though is that once I increase the width of the column, even if I decrease the column size back to its original width, the double scroll bars are still present.....

I also just noticed that when i flip over to the second page of the report, the double scroll bars are no longer present (only the standard vert. and horz. scroll bars) but when I flip back to the first page BOOM, there go the double scroll bars (4 scroll bars total) again.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the width of the scrollbars going just over the full width/height of the page so it lets you scroll to see the Full Scroll bars.  That usually can be fixed by setting the style of the scrollable area to have `box-sizing:border-box`.  If not, set the `width` to something just short of `100%`, like `99.5%`

Comment: P.S. No one plays nicely with Internet Explorer.  They do their best, but nothing is perfect.

Comment: I am using Report Builder 3.0. Where (what property) can I make the change in width you have suggested? I see a few different width properties. I tried changing a few of them (Page Size, Interactive Size) for the report but no luck. Firefox just shows 1 scroll bar at the bottom which is all you really need to scroll to the right.

Comment: I think Mr @MiltoxBeyond lives in the HTML world even though he is 100% correct (right answer, wrong question) but this is SSRS world and we do not have the luxury of setting CSS however, he mad up for it in his second comment. And the problem still exists in ver. 12.0 would you believe IE 10. All I did was change the default border colour from blank to Black so not even a width change has caused the same dilemma. Ruddy Microsoft they have a lot to answer for. They design a system and it doesn't even render properly in their own browser - the mind boggles. Works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: Actually I should say it renders correctly in Chrome however, for a drill thru report (i.e. link on a textbox that when clicked opens another SSRS report) the Back button does not reload the report as does IE if it has parameters. I do not have any other browser installed so I will stick with IE and find a solution. Probably has something to do with report settings like page size and margins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't neccessarily have an answer, but I do have a workaround that I think you/others might find helpful for this question.

I noticed this with a recent report I created and found out the following things could be done to not display the double horizontal scroll bars.

1. In IE9, resize the size of the browser window to any size (anything but maximized).  You should then only see one horizontal scroll bar.
2. Use a different version of IE.  I used IE11 and verified there is always only one horizontal scroll bar.

Please Note:
My particular issue using IE9 also included the need to use the right-most scrollbar and scroll down in order to reveal the second horizontal scrollbar.  The amount to scroll down was so small, that I originally only thought there was one horizontal scroll bar which had not space to scroll left or right.